# Getting an error as "Wrong python code defined for salary rule" odoo 11

Tags: python, odoo, rules

I am getting an error while calling a function from ODOO 11 Payslip, when calling a function that is defined in my code. The error says, "Wrong python code defined for salary rule Overtime Pay (OT)."

The code I wrote is as below -

```
class SalaryRuleFunctions(models.Model):

    _inherit = 'hr.payslip'

    @api.multi
    def get_overtime_salary(self):

        emp_id = self.employee_id
        dt_from = self.date_from
        dt_to = self.date_to
        emp_rec = self.env['x_attendance_summary'].search([('employee_id', '=', emp_id), ('start_date', '=', dt_from), ('end_date', '=', dt_to)])[0]

        g_sal = (self.contract_id.x_ctc_gross / emp_rec.max_days)
        o_day = emp_rec.x_overtime_days_normal

        result = g_sal * o_day
        return result
```

The code inside the Salary Rule for Overtime Pay is as below -

```
result = payslip.env['hr.payslip'].get_overtime_salary()
```

I am not sure if the function is ever called. I tried putting in some messages also in my function to know if there is an error on function code. But, none of those messages show up, indicating that the function has never been called and the error is thrown from the salary rule itself.

Is it that env variable is not available in Odoo 11? Or something else?

Thanks in advance for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is use the variable contract instead of payslip.

```
result = contract.env['hr.payslip'].get_overtime_salary()
```